# Params not being passed when navigating between screens react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this button in first screen

```
 <Button rounded   title='next'    onPress= {() => navigate('nextScreen', { text: this.props.navigation.state.params.text, name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name})}>
```

and I want to display the text and the name in nextScreen    but there is no result 
, here is the code

```
 <Text style={{direction: 'rtl', fontSize: 15, padding: 5 }}> • {this.props.navigation.state.params.name}-  {this.props.navigation.state.params.text} </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button rounded   title='next'    onPress= {() => navigate('nextScreen', { text: this.props.navigation.state.params.text, name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name})}>
```

in the above code you are sending text and name as

```
{ text: this.props.navigation.state.params.text, name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name}
```

check weather you are getting text and name from the previous screen.the values should not be null

Comment: the name and text that you are sending to the nextScreen are from the current screen or you are getting that from the previous screen?

Comment: Im getting the name and text from the previous screen

Comment: check the values ( name and text ) that you are getting from the previous screen by putting console in the present screen.  eg: console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.text)